# How to use "as"

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, as

More difficulty with "as":

> 1 laws ***as*** they existed in the 1900s
>   2 laws ***as*** they relate to public schools

According to standard English, the two sentences mean respectively:

> 3 laws ***in the form*** they existed in in the 1900s
>   4 laws ***in the way*** they relate to public schools

Sentence 3 makes sense, because it means "laws of a certain type".  But, I couldn't quite make the same connection with sentence 4.  Laws are not action, so using "in the way" with laws seem strange.

Comment: I just posted an answer to [another question about as](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26832/3281) an hour ago. I quoted a few sub-entries from a grammar book. Though it's a different question, you might find it useful.

Comment: *noun + as + [the comparison or justification]* when used in such structure generally means *the context of...[whatever is said later].* Consider... *laws, as they happened to be in the context of public school.*

Comment: I also posted another [recent answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/49107/6700) to a question about “as”. It’s not exactly about your question, but the principle explained there explains the phrases you’re asking about. It might provide another useful angle (varying familiar phrases rather than following rules).

Answer (score 1):

The action in the sentence isn't the law itself, but the law's relation:

> Laws in the way they **relate** to public schools.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the second example that you mention, "as" has more that meaning:

> as (conj.): In accordance with which or with the way in which

Another example would be:

```
The hotel is quite comfortable as such establishments go. The sun is hot, as everyone knows.
```

For other possible meanings you can check this [link](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/As).

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence-fragment

> laws as they relate to public schools

means:

...laws that either directly regulate public schools or whose provisions have an indirect effect upon public schools.

"as" here means "to the extent that" or "insofar as".