# "So am I" or "So do I"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, responses

What would be the correct way to reply to a statement such as:  "I belong to this group"

Would it be "So do I" or "So am I"?

Comment: Check out 302.4 in one of my old answers: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26832/3281. Because the right auxiliary verb for "belong" is "do", you'd want to use *"So do I,"* in this case.

Comment: To be grammatical the speaker should be clear about in what form the verb in the first person's statement. Verb "do","be",or "have" accordingly, that makes sure you use it right.

Answer (score 13):

You use "so am I" when you are responding to some form of the verb *be*:

> I'm hungry.  So am I.
>   I'm eating ice cream.  So am I.

You use "so have I" when you are responding to some form of the verb *have*.  You will always use "so have I" when *have* is the auxiliary verb for the present perfect:

> I've eaten too much ice cream.  So have I.

You may use either "so do I" or "so have I" when *have* is used on its own to denote possession of something:

> I have an ice cream cone.  So do I/so have I.

Americans in this case will pretty much always use "so do I", whereas British will use one or the other.

Other auxiliary verbs repeat the verb used as well:

> I would like some ice cream. So would I.
>   I will bring some ice cream. So will I.
>   I should eat some ice cream. So should I.
>   I must eat some ice cream. So must I.
>   I ought to eat some ice cream. Me too!

("So ought I" sounds hopelessly stilted.  You can always say "me too" instead of any of these.)

Ordinary verbs will always use "so do I":

> I like ice cream.  So do I.
>   I need to eat some ice cream.  So do I.

Comment: "_("So ought I" sounds hopelessly stilted. You can always say "me too" instead of any of these.)_" Or: So should I.

Comment: @Mori Funny when I just reread this that "so should I" occurred to me as well. It took you four years to mention it, and me another three years to catch up! :)

Answer (score 1):

So do I *means* I do too .
So am I *means* I am too
In conclusion, **So do I** would be the answer.
LOOK AT THIS CAREFULLY:

> I belong to this group. I do too.
>   I belong to this group. So do I.

But if you use *So am I* it wouldnt make any sense.

> I belong to this group. I am too.
>   I belong to this group. So am I.

Afterwards, the main verb is always referred to *do, does and did*. **BELONG** IS THE MAIN VERB.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question contains the word "belong", then "So do I" is more preferable.

As an auxiliary we use *do* for most verbs (except not for be, will, have got and modal verbs), therefore, *do* is selected.

Comment: This answer looks fine to me. But maybe it needs some expansion. Maybe you could elaborate a bit on why we use "so do I" with "belong".

Comment: Ok, I will edit.