# Meaning of "as is an increased awareness in the role of tourism in the delivery on the post-2015 Development Agenda"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, grammaticality

I ran into this sentence in [Tourism and the Sustainable Development Goals, issued by UNWTO, under Goal 17](http://www.e-unwto.org/doi/book/10.18111/9789284417254) :

> ...Indeed, public/public cooperation and public/private partnerships are a necessary and core foundation for tourism development, *as is an increased awareness in the role of tourism in the delivery on the post-2015 Development Agenda*.

The part *as is an increased awareness in the role of tourism in the delivery on the post-2015 Development Agenda* is a bit confusing to me.

Is it grammatical?

What/where is the subject of the verb *is*?

What does this part mean?

Isn't the preposition of *awareness* **of**? Why **in** has been used?

What does *delivery on* mean?

Comment: Except for the preposition, this old answer of mine should be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26832/3281. Look for 326.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public/public cooperation and public/private partnerships are a necessary and core foundation for tourism development, as is an increased awareness in the role of tourism in the delivery on the post-2015 Development Agenda.

Let's break it down.  The core sentence is:

> [A1] & [A2] are a necessary and core foundation for [B], as is [C]

Although it's possible the sentence is:

> [A1] & [A2] are a necessary and core foundation for [B], as is [C], in the delivery (of) [D]

Without more context it's unclear whether "in the delivery on the post-2015 Development Agenda" applies to "the role of tourism", or possibly *all* the other conditions in the sentence.

With the last (and most confusing) part of the sentence, the author is saying that either:

> "an increased awareness in the role of tourism" is a necessary and core foundation for "tourism development"

or

> "an increased awareness in the role of tourism in the delivery on the post-2015 Development Agenda" is a necessary and core foundation for "tourism development"

(Note: I don't have enough context to know exactly what all this means.  I'm just relating the parts of the sentence.)

To rephrase the last part,

> "it is important to make more people aware of the role of tourism in delivering on (i.e., *implementing*) the post-2015 agenda"

Government agencies do love that passive voice, though.  Often you have to guess at the implied subject based on context.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the report, I noticed more than a few grammatical errors and typos. The italicized part of the sentence seems to have some minor errors, but even with those fixed its meaning is unclear.

I believe the italicized part of the sentence is saying that

1) Tourism will play an important role in the implementing the post-2015 Development Agenda.

2) Increased awareness of that role (by the global community?) is an important foundation for tourism development.