# As is vs. As it is

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

[SOURCE](https://www.google.jo/amp/s/www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/01/22/letters-from-the-january-22-2018-issue/amp): NEW YORKER MAGAZINE

> **As is usually the case** when a literary debate erupts, we’re not talking about the mechanics of story composition; this is a conversation about racial and cultural power and prestige.

Why does the bold part sound awkward or weird?

Isn’t it supposed to go like:

> - Usually, as the case is; or usually, as it is

I think “as is the case” is a kind of inversion”

Comment: "Isn’t it supposed to ***goes*** like:" not "go"?

Comment: @Raj33 : No, Bavyan had it correct.  "It's supposed to ____" takes an infinitive, not a conjugated verb.

Comment: @stangdon I have never seen or heard it before "supposed to goes". I think I have to ask a question about this. Please have a look at this Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Supposed+to+go%2Csupposed+to+goes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSupposed%20to%20go%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Bavyan Yaldo, I'm not saying that's wrong. I'm an English learner too, so I want to confirm that.

Comment: Well, it is a misunderstanding between you. Stangdon, if you look at my original version of my question, you would see i had a mistyped mistake, so  once @Raj33 notified me, I immediately correct my mistake. So you, standgon, though that raj implied i have to replace goes instead of go.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26817/why-are-the-subject-and-the-verb-inverted-after-the-conjunction-as/26832

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as), in your sentence, **as** is a conjunction meaning **in the same way**. Here is the example that they provide:

> As is often the case with children, Amy was completely better by the time the doctor arrived.

When used in this way, the first clause seems not to have a subject, which makes it sound weird.

Other authorities (for example [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as), pronoun definition 2) consider this usage to be a pronoun, which can then serve as a subject of the clause.

If you try to insert a subject like **it** or **this**, **as** changes its meaning to **because**, for example:

> As **this** is the case, we can deduce that X is never negative

**Usually** is placed after the BE-verb because it applies only to the first clause. You cannot move **usually** before **as** because then it would apply the second clause, not the first. Here is an example that shows this effect:

> Usually, when the sun shines, we go to the beach.

Comment: Well, why do we put “it” in this sense “as it is known” instead of “as is known”?  As **it** is usually the case....

Comment: The fragments of sentences that you have quoted are all valid in an appropriate context. If **it** is present, the meaning will be **because**, and if **it** is not present, the meaning will be **in the same way that**.